# Understanding C++ Struct syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I am learning iOS development and have come across a snipet of code in an SDK which I am having trouble deciphering.

```
struct PinchScaleState
{
    PinchScaleState ()
    : currentScale (1.f)
    , initialPinchScale (1.f)
    {}

    float currentScale;
    float initialPinchScale;
};
```

I get that the above code is defining a C Struct which has the properties

```
float currentScale;
float initialPinchScale;
```

But I am unsure what the following is doing

```
 PinchScaleState ()
 : currentScale (1.f)
 , initialPinchScale (1.f)
 {}
```

I am guessing it is setting up initial values but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a C++ constructor to me. In C++, the distinction between a `struct` and a `class` is somewhat muddy.

Comment: The term you'll want to search  for is "initializer list". (And your guessing is good.)

Comment: @user3386109 it's not "muddy" in any way. Both declare a class, but the content and base classes of the `struct` are `public` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a C++ constructor. Following the `:` is a constructor initialization list, which is setting the values of `currentScale` and `initialPinchScale`, like you guessed.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! I found the following article helpful http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519